# I am getting an error with sqlite3_prepare_v2

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, xcode4

I am creating an app, and doing update with sqlite. Here is my piece of code given below:

```
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appforoffice.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
    }

    const char *sql = "UPDATE settings SET `value`='Off' WHERE `type`=?";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [updateType UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(sqlite3_step(updateStmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {
                NSLog(@"Update Done successfuly");
            }
            else {
                 NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error while binding variable. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
```

But guys, **I am not getting any error**. But the problem is that, **the database table is not being effected by the query**. I am sure the query is perfectly alright.

I am confused about the problem, can't find any way to get out of this.

Comment: You'll need to post the query and possibly the schema if you want to solve this type of database issue.

Comment: @SoumalyaBanerjee Could you please check issue mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916124/sqlite3-prepare-v2-exc-bad-access-in-ios-10. I also facing similar problem after upgrade to iOS-10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sqlite3_prepare_v2()` doesn't return boolean, so testing its return value with `!` is wrong.  From the [reference](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_prepare):

> On success, the sqlite3_prepare() family of routines return SQLITE_OK;
>   otherwise an error code is returned.

So your code should look more like this:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [updateType UTF8String], -1,
        SQLITE_TRANSIENT) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        ... call update API ...
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while binding variable. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

**EDIT** (after the question was updated with the whole query):

I don't like the look of the ` characters in the query; remove them and it *should* work.

Comment: I did exactly, what you've told me to do. Now I am not getting an error **Error while binding variable. 'bind or column index out of range'**.

Comment: OK, the bind column indexes start at 0; change `1` in the statement to `0`.

Comment: I solved the error, there was a silly mistake in my query. Now I am not getting any error. But the main issue is, update query is not running, i.e. databse table is not effected. But the query is perfectly alright.

Comment: I have edited my question, after editing my code, as you suggested.

Comment: Yes because, using 0, gives same error **Error while binding variable. 'bind or column index out of range'**, when making it 1 is solving the error. And I think 1 refers to the first position.

Comment: I have re-edited the code, and now here is my entire code given with my question.

Comment: @SoumalyaBanerjee My comment about column indexes starting at 0 was wrong, as you say, they start at 1.

Comment: @trojanfoe I also facing similar issue mention here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916124/sqlite3-prepare-v2-exc-bad-access-in-ios-10 Could you please check.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use sql command straight forward without any prepare or bind Methods

```
sqlite3_exec(database,[sql UTF8String],nil,nil,nil);
```

where sql is an NSString which has the update statement ,Just make sure your db is open

hope that helps

Comment: When I am using `sqlite3_exec`, I am not getting any error, it is not taking any effect, i.e. update query is not running. But the query is perfectly alright.

Comment: am using it always and it works , make sure you opened the database  'if(sqlite3_open([_dbPath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)'