# sqlite3_prepare_v2 exc_bad_access in iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, ios10

I have use sqlite in my iOS project for database. In iOS 9 all things are working perfectly. Now i have update new Xcode. But app is crashes many times at 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'.

Also, i am not closing database overtime. And open it only once.
I have added DB open in below code b'acs in debug i got DB close. But still got crash.

[crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8dow.png)

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Please help if someone has faced the same. ANY HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATE.

Comment: The only hint I see from that is "address=0x0".  Check the values you're passing to the call to make sure they aren't unexpectedly nil.

Comment: I am not passing any nil value. App is crashing while executing 'sqlite3_prepare_v2' .

Comment: Any update for above crash ??? @PhillipMills

Comment: No.  It says it's getting an address of 0 and you say you're not passing anything like that.  I don't see any other useful information.

Comment: Could you please share the project? I have similar issue, perhaps we can solve it together. Thanks!

Comment: While performing Database write operation on same time with single DB object, than you receive this crash. So, try to make synchronized all write operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in line 2592.

Do not treat key as string when passing it to sqlite3_key(...)
Not sure how you generate key but if first byte is set '\0' then strlen return 0
(which may happen pretty often if you use some autogenerated helper based on NSData random bytes)

sqlite3_key definition:

```
SQLITE_API int SQLITE_STDCALL sqlite3_key(sqlite3 *db, const void *pKey, int nKey)
```

It expects nKey bytes where "\0" is allowed too

Instead try:

```
 NSData *passBytes = [g_sqlite_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 int status = sqlite3_key(contactDB, passBytes.bytes, passBytes.length);
 if (status != SQLITE_OK) {
      // handle error and return
 }
 // continue...
```